# Highcharts Error while loading solid gauge module

Tags: highcharts

I have highcharts used with highcharts-vue.

I have several plugins loaded and working as expected:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue';
import stockInit from 'highcharts/modules/stock';
import noDataToDisplay from 'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display';
import solidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';

if (typeof Highcharts === 'object' && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  stockInit(Highcharts);
  solidGauge(Highcharts);
  noDataToDisplay(Highcharts);
}

Vue.use(HighchartsVue, {tagName: 'charts'});
```

But the solid-gauge module I just added generates an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at a (solid-gauge.js:15:327)
    at eval (solid-gauge.js:15:388)
    at eval (solid-gauge.js:16:308)
    at eval (solid-gauge.js:19:291)
    at f (solid-gauge.js:11:175)
    at eval (solid-gauge.js:14:442)
    at eval (highcharts.js:34:72)
    at Module../plugins/highcharts.js (app.js:5244:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (runtime.js:854:30)
```

I hardly see how I can investigate further from this step.

I did update my highcharts npm dependency up to `10.0.1` but the error still occurs.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import and initialize the `highcharts-more` module before `solid-gauge`.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue';
import hcMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import stockInit from 'highcharts/modules/stock';
import noDataToDisplay from 'highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display';
import solidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';

if (typeof Highcharts === 'object' && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  hcMore(Highcharts);
  stockInit(Highcharts);
  solidGauge(Highcharts);
  noDataToDisplay(Highcharts);
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2dqL70hy/